# Run a non-GUI application as a service in windows 8

Tags: windows-services

I have done this in linux and it was pretty easy but in windows I'm lost!
Is there any way to run a command line application in windows as a service?
My goal is to run tor in the background without using vidalia bundle.
Thanx in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SC will happily install any executable as a Windows Service, your service will start only if the executable is a true service, written to interact with the Service Control manager (SCM).

If your application is a regular, non-service application or batch file, you will need a utility like [Microsoft's SRVANY](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) to intercept the start request from the SCM and run your application. [Commercial alternatives](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunBatchFileAsAService.html) are available as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SC` command to do this.  You will need to launch command prompt as an administrator and use the following command:

```
sc create <new_service_name> binpath= "<path_to_the_executable>"
```

Please be aware that you will need to use quotes around the "Path_to_the_executable".
And don't forget " " (space) after `binPath=` (otherwise it may not work)

More information on the sc command and its usage can be found on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) Microsoft KnowledgeBase article, and in  [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) article from TechNet (for advanced usage).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The service is created but looks like when I start it windows is waiting for some kinda response from the program and it fails because tor does not do such a thing! this is the error it shows: "error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"